# $K$ theory of $C^*$ algebra is different to algebraic $K$ Theory?

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, k-theory, topological-k-theory, algebraic-k-theory

> Is the $K_0$ group for a $C^*$ algebras  $A$ same as that for the $K_0$ group of ring $A$ from algebraic $K$ theory?

We assume $A$ is unital (I am not sure if this matters), i.e. what is an example where the these to $K$ theory groups are distinct when restricted to the category of $C^*$ algebras?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $K_0$ group of a C*-algebra is the same as the (algebraic) $K_0$ group of it considered as a ring.

Comment: Is there a reference for this? Or may you outline a proof ?

Comment: I suppose your definition of algebraic K-theory is in terms of idempotents and algebraic equivalence of them. Then you may have a look at Blackadar's book "K-Theory for Operator Algebras", Lemma  4.6.4. If you have the definition by finiteily generated projective modules in mind, have a look at Rosenbergs Book "Algebraic K-Theory and its applications", Lemma 1.2.1.

Comment: Then I am quite lost, we have the excision results for algebraic $K$-theory, why can't we directly apply to it to that for $K$ theory of operator algebras? The excision proof seems really messy in operator $K$-theory.